# Are all monotonically normal manifolds of dimension at least two metrizable?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, manifolds

Alan Dow and Frank Tall recently proved the consistency of the statement *Every hereditarily normal manifold of dimension at least two is metrizable*.

See: *Dow, Alan; Tall, Franklin D.*, [**Hereditarily normal manifolds of dimension greater than one may all be metrizable**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/tran/7916), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 372, No. 10, 6805-6851 (2019). [ZBL1427.54006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1427.54006).

This suggests a natural question:

> Is it true in ZFC that every [monotonically normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonically_normal_space) manifold of dimension at least two is metrizable?

The Long Line is an example of a one-dimensional non-metrizable monotonically normal manifold.

NOTE: By "manifold" I mean a Hausdorff space which is locally euclidean.

Comment: Dow and Tall's result doesn't use a supercompact. The supercompact was used in Nyikos' earlier result.

Comment: Ok, I see, none of the consequences of PFA(S)[S] they're using requires large cardinals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear that that it is true. The result is due to Z. Balogh and E. Rudin and appears in their paper *Monotone Normality*, Top. App. **47**,  (1992), 115-127. The statement to quote is the following.

> **Corollary 2.3.(e).** A manifold of dimension $\geq2$ is metrizable if and only if it is monotonically normal.

This follows easily from the first of the two main results in the paper.

> **Theorem I.** A monotonically normal space is paracompact if and only if it does not have a closed subspace homeomorphic to a stationary subset of a regular uncountable cardinal.

It's worth mentioning that with a little thought it's not hard to repackage the dimension hypothesis so as to include all manifolds.

> A manifold is metrisable if and only if it is separable and monotonically normal.